# Is it possible to compress data in SQL Server using zlib?

Tags: sql-server, compression, zlib

Is it possible to compress data (programmatically) in SQL Server using zlib compression? It's just one column in a specific table that needs compressing.

I'm not a SQL Server person myself - I've tried to find if there's anything available but not had much joy.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean only using SQL Server itself? If not then writing code which reads the column data, compresses it using a library such as zlibnet (https://zlibnet.codeplex.com/) and then updates the database column again would do it. The column would need to be of a type suitable for storing the expected length of binary data which results from the compression.

Comment: Ideally yes it would be using SQL Server itself as we don't really have the resource/skills available to write something in C#.

Comment: You can add .NET assemblies to SQL Server and use custom functions written in C#. Maybe this is a way.

Comment: Why do you want to compress the data with zlib? If it's a lot of data, e.g. large files and you don't need to query it, it might be better to store it outside the database.

Comment: I don't think SQL Server has any native capability for that; you'd need to add to it, which means getting into C# or something similar. What is the purpose of doing this? I'm thinking another approach might be necessary.

Comment: We're migrating data from a system on SQL Server onto an Oracle-based system and the data on the Oracle system needs to be in compressed format (it is read by an application that is expecting compressed data). The main reason for wanting to compress it on the SQL Server side is that there is a lot of data to transfer and if we're able to compress the data prior to transferring to Oracle, it will cut down the amount of time taken (otherwise it has to be done as part of the transfer into Oracle)