# How can I decode data (probably ZLIB) using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, compression, zlib

I have an encrypted files in the table `DOCUMENTDATA`:

[image: Compressed data]

Example of the data:

```
0x78DA2B2E492C2A0100068F022F

0x78DA333232335200034597D49CCCB2D4A2CAF89AB89AD0829CFCC494D4947838000A3AE7E7A56516E5A28986181A2914A526A702F5C22478B90008741E52
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c637)

It looks like ZLIB format because of the first bytes `0x78DA`.

How can I decode it?

Comment: Yes it is zlib and it contains sth like: `2262      !Delivery_|^|Uploaded__________|^|Confirmed__________|^|T12 received_______`; `809       0000013685                    |^|629027|^|36|^|err|^|err|^|20150701                      |^|1|^|MCS`, `H;ut0000222;701;2015-07-01 00:00:00;;ut001500763;;;;b
I;ut001500763;127242310;6;PC` and so on. To decompress it inside SQL Server you probably need to use CLR function

Comment: Thank you for the response, this is the exact data, which I want to get from dbase.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, they are zlib strings. The first example is the string `start`. The second is `2262      !Delivery_|^|Uploaded__________|^|Confirmed__________|^|T12 received_______`. They are not encrypted.

How to decompress depends on how you are accessing the SQL server. What language are you using? On what platform?

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation of zlib strings. I am using SQL server management studio, I want to create a second table with decoded data. CLR function, which offered @lad2025, is good for me, but I haven`t found it on http://zlib.net/. It looks like I am not the only one with this request, I have found a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324017/is-it-possible-to-compress-data-in-sql-server-using-zlib.

Comment: I will try to create a CLR function using ZLIB C# source code, and come back if I'll succeed.